# AWS DynamoDB iOS SDK silently failing but always returning success status

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I've created an iOS application following AWS Mobile SDK examples using AWSiOSSDKv2.

I've successfully been able to connect with an unauthorized Cognito account to DynamoDB and write to the table.  I log into AWS, check the table and see my records are there.

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
[[dynamoDBObjectMapper save:tableRow] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (!task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully inserted the data into the table.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to insert the data into the table.");
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

However, now I want to test what will happen in a failure.  I deliberately try to cause an error by changing the dynamoDBTableName to something that does not exist.  Unfortunately, my code always returns success even tho it was not.

I found in another thread someone recommending putting logging to verbose which I did.

```
[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;
```

And in the console, I do see that AWSLogger displays an error:

> [{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException","Message":"User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/Cognito_xxxxxxxxUnauth_DefaultRole/iOS-Provider
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:table/xxxxxxxx"}]

However, In my code above, it always writes "Successfully inserted the data into the table.".

I've even tried modifying AWS Mobile Examples and can reproduce the same bug.  I've also tried installing the POD and manually adding the AWSiOSSDKv2 framework to my project, neither fix the issue.

Has anyone run into this issue and does anyone know how to resolve?  I'm trying to create an unauthorized user who only has write access to the dynamodb table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=590158) of the SDK, and the fix is on its way.

In the meanwhile, if you are using CocoaPods, adding the following lines to [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.m L154](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/DynamoDB/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.m#L154) should fix it:

```
if (task.error) {
    return task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yosuke, this indeed fixed the issue.